# Redirecting to email editor compose screen - set from address (sugarcrm)

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am redirecting to the compose email screen like this:

```
 SugarApplication::redirect("index.php?action=Compose&module=Emails&return_module=Cases&return_action=DetailView&return_id=".$this->bean->id."&recordId=".$email_id);
```

This works but the problem is: Right now it always goes to the current user's email address, I would like it to go to the system admin address. Is there anyway to set the from address when redirecting like this?